# WSDL SOAP call via PHP - parameters being ignored

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm trying to use certain filters out of a remote WSDL web service. I get no errors when trying to do so, but all I get is the full list of data with those parameters being ignored.

Calling `$client->__getFunctions()` retrieves a blank page, so I'm not sure what to do.

This is the XML:

```
<s:element name="Entities">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Format" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="wherefilter" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ordercondition" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

And this is how I'm trying to do it with PHP:

```
public static function fetch($name = 'Entities')
{
    $base = 'http://tempuri.org/';

    $client = new \SoapClient(null, [
        'location'   => '...',
        'uri'        => '...',
        'trace'      => 1,
        'exceptions' => true
    ]);

    $params = ['Format' => 'JSON'];

    try {
        // $params is being ignored
        $data = $client->__soapCall($name, $params, ['soapaction' => $base . $name]);

        return $data;
    }
    catch (\SoapFault $ex) {
        abort(403, $ex); 
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        die($ex);
    }
}
```

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After circling the internet for an answer I had to restructure the code in order to make this work. I'm not entirely sure why the old setup didn't work but this is how it does work now:

```
public static function fetch()
{
    $options = [
        'trace'         => 1,
        'exceptions'    => true
    ];

    $client = new \SoapClient('my_soap_url.asmx?WSDL', $options);

    try {
        $input = new \stdClass();
        $input->Format = "JSON";

        $data = $client->Entities($input);

        return reset($data);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'REQUEST:' . $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() . $client->__getLastRequest() . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
        echo 'RESPONSE:' . $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() . $client->__getLastResponse();   
    }
}
```